# Monitor elements of a webpage & receive real-time alerts

Tags: monitoring

Looking for a solution for our help center employees. They're using inContact and Zendesk to accept calls, emails, and chat from our users. The problem is that integrating the two programs removes the ability to receive real-time alerts when a new ticket comes in. This is obviously an essential feature and I'm looking to replicate the behavior with either a plugin, native app or other freeware. Everyone's using macs so app store products are acceptable and any freeware needs to be mac-specific. All employees use Chrome.

## What We Need

There is a widget inside of the inContact dashboard that can be customized to show the number of incoming tickets. Whenever that number goes up (not down, and not stagnant), some kind of alert should pop up. A sound would be ideal but just a popup is okay too. Specifically, the inContact dashboard can often be buried under other windows so the alert needs to draw attention even if the window itself is covered.

The section of the page that needs to be watched is just a div, so anything that ties into the source code of a page would work. We can't have programs that monitor an "image" for updates since it needs to be able to interpret numbers (trigger only on n+1) rather than trigger any time an "image" changes (which would trigger even for n-1). There is no RSS feed available.

A small price tag is acceptable given how important this feature is to the department. I would put our max at around $15 / user / month, although less is better.

## What We've Tried

- [Page Monitor Pro](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-monitor-pro/aggebfalegkdaebfdldpaolhmlalbakp?hl=en) - Couldn't be customized to watch the correct app. There's just not enough customization to make it work.
- [Distill](https://distill.io/apps/web-monitor) - Setup worked exactly as expected, but the app is unreliable. Employees are complaining that it only works for a period of time before the automatic checks stop being automatic. The only solution is to delete the customization and rebuild it, which is incredibly far from ideal.

Comment: If you ever found an answer, I wonder if it would be relevant to share here: "Button that toggles in real-time the visibility of an element on my webpage" https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/71261/14834